# Table Upper Corner

Tags: tables

could anybody help me please?? I'm trying to get a table like this:
[image]

However, as adding code in second column, the 'i' cell keeps expanding:
[image]

Does anybody know how to get the 'i' width fixed and expand the 'Component' instead?? There might be a command but I cannot find it...

This is the code example:

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Component $\rightarrow$} & i& 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
 j& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Process 1} & A & ZZ \\
 \hline
 1& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Process 2} & AF    &AFG\\
 \hline
 2& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{This is a very long line...} &  AX  & ALA   \\
 \hline

\end{tabular}
\label{tab:label}
\end{table}
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }   
\hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Component $\rightarrow$ \hfill\vrule\hspace{\tabcolsep}i} & 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
 j& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Process 1} & A & ZZ \\
 \hline
 1& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Process 2} & AF    &AFG\\
 \hline
 2& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{This is a very long line...} &  AX  & ALA   \\
 \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why five columns? The second and third are always spanned, so the result cannot be different with just four, with `\multicolumn{2}` in the first row and no `\multicolumn` in the following rows.

Comment: @egreg: No idea, I thought that it is from the real tabular, perhaps the column is split further on.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!! And its true that now one of the columns is not needed... Thanks again. Regards, Vicente